# directive template attribute name confusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I attempt to use the following angular directive definition:

```
module.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            'title': '@'
        },
        template: '<div data-title="{{title}}" ng-transclude></div>',
        require: "?ngModel"
    }
}
```

with the following html:

```
<test title='test title'></test>
```

{{title}} does not get replaced with 'test title' as I would expect.  If I use an attribute name other than data-title the directive works as I would expect.  For example if I use datatitle instead of data-title, {{title}} gets replaced correctly.  Do I need to escape data-title in some way?  Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in later versions of angular.  I upgraded from 1.0.8 to 1.1.5 and the problem went away.